# Simple if statement inside jquery $.each function not returning right value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, if-statement, each

I'm unable to get a basic if statement inside a jquery $.each loop working. I have a json object that I loop through, and if the value entered in a text box is found in the json object, I return a flag I set as false. But for some reason, the if statement is not executing. Here is the code:

```js
var authorlist = [
  {"AUTHOR":"DONNA EDWARDS","COUNTRY":"USA","REGION":"MIDWEST"},
  {"AUTHOR":"EMERALD JONES","COUNTRY":"UK","REGION":"EU"},
  {"AUTHOR":"SHAKESPEARE","COUNTRY":"UK","REGION":"EU"}];

function checkName() {
  var nameIsValid = true;
  var nametocheck = $("#name").val();
  $.each(authorlist, function(index, val){
    //console.log(val.AUTHOR);
    if(nametocheck == val.AUTHOR) {
      //console.log(val.AUTHOR);
      nameIsValid = false;
      return false;
    }
  });
  return nameIsValid;
}

$("#btnCheck").on("click", function(){
  console.log("The name entered is valid: " + checkName());
});
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" name="paymentInformation" id="paymentInformation" action="verifyOrder.cfm" method="post" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <fieldset class="col-sm-12">

      <!-- Row 1 -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <label for="id2" class="col-6 col-form-label">
            Book Name
          </label>
          <input type="form-control" placeholder="Book Name" type="text" id="id2" name="id2" class="col-10">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnCheck">Check</button>
        </div>
 
      </div>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wqnkz4v7/

Comment: Your logic of "name is valid" seems to be backwards.  Did you mean to say if the name entered by the user IS in the list then it is an invalid?  Or rather the other way around?

Comment: @Leo Nix - Yes, but the order shouldn't matter in the if statement. Is that why you downvoted my question? If it is, that's got to be the dumbest reason. If not, my apologies.

Comment: I have not down voted your question :-)

Comment: Down voters should really leave a comment so the recipient knows why and correct if necessary.

Comment: @Leo Nix - I agree, thanks for suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit following

```
var nametocheck = $("#id2").val();
```

or Use following

```
$("input[name='name']").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to address the right id.

```
var nametocheck = $("#id2").val();
//                   ^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you have is in `var nametocheck = $("#name").val();`.

The selector according to the html should be "#id2".